# Flutter pubspec.yaml Android versionCode

Tags: android, flutter, dart-pub

My app before using Flutter had

```
android:versionCode="17"
android:versionName="17"
```

In my Flutter application in `pubspec.yaml`, I have to set a version as `x.y.z` and I am trying set the new version to `19.0.0`.
But when I try to install the application on my device that has a version with `android:versionCode="17"` installed, I get an error message saying that the version on device is bigger than version I am trying to install.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `flutter.versionCode` local property gets populated using the part after the `+` of the `pubspec.yaml` version.

This means that for Android, the `pubspec.yaml` version is parsed as follows:

```
version: {versionName}+{versionCode}
```

The example from your questions would consequently look like this in order to work (in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
name: ...
version: 19.0.0+19

...
```

As a side note, it is idiomatic for Dart to follow [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0-rc.1.html), although the `+` suffix does not work as it should when trying to build for Android with Flutter as I explained.